# Ayuda con el error "Action {$action} not defined." en Laravel

Tags: laravel

En mi controlador llamado `DocenteController` tengo la función:

```
public function editarUsuario($id)
{.....}
```

En el archivo de rutas:

```
Route::resource('misvistas/docente', 'DocenteController');
```

y lo mando a traer:

```
href="{{ URL::action('DocenteController@editarUsuario', $usuario->idusuario) }}"
```

Tengo otras funciones y esas si las ejecuta (index, create, store, ...)

Pero con esta función me arroja el error

> "Action .../DocenteController@editarUsuario not defined."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando utilizas

```
Route::resource('misvistas/docente', 'DocenteController');
```

Te genera las siguientes 7 rutas por defecto:

```
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Method    | URI                              | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| POST      | misvistas/docente                | docente.store    | App\Http\Controllers\DocenteController@store                           | web          |
| GET|HEAD  | misvistas/docente                | docente.index    | App\Http\Controllers\DocenteController@index                           | web          |
| GET|HEAD  | misvistas/docente/create         | docente.create   | App\Http\Controllers\DocenteController@create                          | web          |
| PUT|PATCH | misvistas/docente/{docente}      | docente.update   | App\Http\Controllers\DocenteController@update                          | web          |
| GET|HEAD  | misvistas/docente/{docente}      | docente.show     | App\Http\Controllers\DocenteController@show                            | web          |
| DELETE    | misvistas/docente/{docente}      | docente.destroy  | App\Http\Controllers\DocenteController@destroy                         | web          |
| GET|HEAD  | misvistas/docente/{docente}/edit | docente.edit     | App\Http\Controllers\DocenteController@edit                            | web          |
```

Puedes comprobar las rutas disponibles con el comando `php artisan route:list`.

Por lo que `DocenteController@editarUsuario` no es una ruta definida validad, para poder usarla antes debes de crearla, para que apunte al método indicado:

```
Route::get('misvistas/mi_ruta/{id}', 'DocenteController@editarUsuario');
```

o puedes sobreescribir la ruta existente creada con `resource` haciendo coincidir la ruta (`misvistas/docente/{docente}/edit` en este caso) para que apunte al método y controlador que queramos.

```
Route::get('misvistas/docente/{docente}/edit', 'DocenteController@editarUsuario')->name('docente.edit');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó. Pensé que con poner el resource se agregarían todas las funciones que creara dentro del controlador.